# Spotlight NOT indexing Postbox messages/emails

Tags: macos, mac, email, spotlight, postbox

I'm currently having a problem with Spotlight where it does NOT index my email from my IMAP Postbox account. I've checked the Mail & Messages from the search results windows in Spotlight and also the option "Allow Spotlight to search messages" within Postbox.

Spotlight does however index Mail out Outlook just fine.

- My default email client is Postbox and I have verified this.
- I made sure that indexing is turned on.
- I've tried re-indexing Postbox and Spotlight multiple times with no avail.
- I'm currently on OS X 10.9.1

Can anyone help?

Comment: UPDATE:
OK, I made some progress: It seems that there was a "Postbox.mdimporter" file missing for Spotlight. Now my email gets indexed, but within Spotlight it does NOT show me a preview like with e.g. Mail. And if I click on the relevant email within Spotlight it does nothing except open Postbox. The metadata seems to be located under -Users/MYUSER/Library/Caches/Metadata/Postbox/ImapMail/....

Answer (score 0):

Found this...

Spotlight indexing is turned off by default. To enable this feature, select Preferences from the Postbox menu, then click on the General icon. Select the checkbox next to "Allow Spotlight to search messages." To try it out (without waiting for Postbox to automatically index your messages for Spotlight), select Indexing from the Tools menu, and then Index This Folder (or Index All Folders). Messages in Postbox will now be included in Spotlight searches.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but as I stated above, I've tried this multiple times, together with re-indexing Spotlight and Postbox.

Comment: I've also tried disabling ALL addons, but also no luck : (